# Add Custom Post Type on the Fly or create an array

Tags: php, posts

I have a unique problem I guess.

I am working on a site and the client needs to have a way in Wordpress backend from where he can add a post, and from the same page (where he is creating a post) he can add sub posts to that post.

He wants to be able to as many sub posts as he wants.

And then he wants on the front end, the main content of the main post to be shwon as a paragraph and the sub posts to be shown as a tabbed window like this in the example: http://www.ricardoruiz.es/tratamientos/dermatologia-estetica/rejuvenecimiento-facial/radiesse

I know how to do the tab thing on the front buy I am not getting an idea on how to have a sub post thing of a main post.

Or this exists at all or not.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If security is not a major issue you can use `$_GET` request to the php file which process the data..

Comment: I want that in the post creation page in the bottom be a button called: Add Tab and when hit that two boxes appear [Title and Content] and below that be the same button which he can use to add more tabs one after another.

Comment: You are probably looking for some jquery..

Answer (score 0):

use `$wp_insert_post` function to create posts and to create sub posts of this use this function again and set post_parent = "name of post you created" see list of all arguments and usage of this function [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Comment: So you mean I should create a separate interface mayself for that and use wp functions to save data?

I was hoping for something easy that could be setup fast?

Comment: i thought you have already created some sort of interface to let your client insert posts

Comment: well this is an easy solution if you want similar functionality you have mentioned in your question. all you have to do is create an admin page and form to let your client fill values for each post.

Answer (score 0):

Teach him to use the parent page feature. (Or just make a link to a new page where the parent page is pre-selected, that should be easy).

Making a new interface for that would just make the customer lose the great auto-saving, concurrent editing and revisions.

Then just get the child pages (on the front end) on the main page and display them inside tabs.

Comment: thanks Marzab for your quick response.

I was thinking the same solution but he does not want to use two interfaces for creating one page, because he considers that to be a one page.

Comment: Well then, if he thinks its one page, so there should also be one input ;) try http://kav.in/wp-ui-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Also you can take new post type and you can manage all things here.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type